# Rate Limiting in laravel to x times per day using RateLimiter

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, symfony-ratelimiter

I am trying to restrict usage of a certain endpoint to 10 times per day per user, and I can see how to do it for a certain number of times per minute. Please note that this is within a controller, not as middleware.

```
    $executed = RateLimiter::attempt(
        'user-send-test-' . Auth::user()->id,
        $perDay = 10,
        function () {
            // some process
        }
    );
```

Comment: the second parameter of `attempt()` is in minutes, as 10 per minutes. it doesn't matter the name you give to the variable `$perDay` or `$perCentury` it will still be per minute.

Comment: right. I know that. I was just showing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To use the rate limiter per day, use the fourth parameter of the method `attemp()` which is the decay (how long an attempt need to be counted for) but I never tested it.

```
$executed = RateLimiter::attempt(
    'user-send-test-' . Auth::user()->id,
    $perDay = 10,
    function () {
        // some process
    },
    60*60*24 // or 86400
    );
```

If you still encounter issues with this example, I suggest you copy the `RateLimiter` class as it is very small and adapt its code.